# Extract expand url from entities which we get from Twitter user json

Tags: python, json, pandas, tweepy

How to get a the expanded_url from entities

```
{"blocked_by": false,
"blocking": false,
"contributors_enabled": false,
"created_at": "Mon Dec 27 16:09:18 +0000 2010",
"default_profile": false,
"default_profile_image": false,
"description": "Wealth Management. Banker. Former elite cyclist. 100% galego. Yield hunter. Until debt tear us apart | USC Alumni",
"entities": {
  "description": {
    "urls": []
  },
  "url": {
    "urls": [
      {
        "display_url": "fanecabrava.substack.com/?utm_source=ac\u2026",
        "expanded_url": "https://fanecabrava.substack.com/?utm_source=account-card&utm_content=writes",
        "indices": [
          0,
          23
        ],
        "url": "shorteners urls i deleted it to post this"
      }
    ]
  }
},
"favourites_count": 3808,
"follow_request_sent": false,
"followers_count": 578,
"following": false,
"friends_count": 465,
"geo_enabled": true,
"has_extended_profile": false,
"id": 231102009,
"id_str": "231102009",
"is_translation_enabled": false,
"is_translator": false,
"lang": null,
```

}

This link has the full json file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zB1mmU5zHbJC6R7ZZESReB0bWGQVTvfx/view?usp=drivesdk

I want only the expanded url for store it into a csv file

Comment: What's the relationship with pandas and did you have knowledge on dictionary?

Comment: I only know basics.i can get till urls after that i use the object expanded_url it giving me error its not object I don't know what is it

Comment: If so, you'd better tell what you have tried and the error you get. I suspect you didn't notice the value of `urls` is list. Try `['urls'][0]['expanded_url']`

Comment: Not working i have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `read_json()` and `apply()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
data = pd.read_json('json.json')

print(data)
# alternative 1: from description section
urls = data['entities'].apply(lambda x: (x['description']['urls'
                              ][0]['expanded_url'
                              ] if len(x['description']['urls'])
                              > 0 else pd.NA))
urls = urls[urls.notna()]


# alternative 2: from url section
urls = data['url']

# expand urls
def expand_url(url):
    if url is None:
      return ''

    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    try:
        return r.headers['location']
    except KeyError:
        return ''
expanded_url = urls.apply(expand_url)
```

**Output:**

```
0                                                       
1                          https://www.sallyturbitt.com/
2                         https://johannesdrooghaag.com/
3                                                       
4
```

Comment: How can i get the expanded url from the url section not description.i tried replace description with url but key error detected

Comment: @ShineMathew I updated my post. It includes now both variants.

Comment: Sir i wanted the expanded urls from the url section the above code is for getting url from it i wanted expanded url from it .how can i get what i have to change

Comment: @ShineMathew I updated my solution to expand the urls from `url` section.

Comment: Ok its working.but i am keeping a record of followers by using this i got the url but for some followers don't have urls so in that place i want to leave it as blank.how can get it with this code.

Comment: @ShineMathew I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot sir.how can i learn this type of coding.which section is this

Comment: @ShineMathew It's a combination of basic python and pandas. You might want to start with introductory tutorials. Please accept the answer if its what you need.

Comment: I have the total of 16k profiles using ur code this error happened

Comment: requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='t.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /b4ZvgmC6al (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022452C8E440>, 'Connection to t.co timed out. (connect timeout=None)')).ism getting this error